# layout distorts on keypad display and on landscape screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Found similar question but could not find best answer.
How to solve Layout problem on keypad display and on landscape screen in android?
Below are the images with problem occurring.[image: Initial layouot]

Above is original layout

Below its after keyboard on screen

[image: layout after keyboard]

In the 2nd picture layout after keyboard,Half button is missing and sign in textview is missing

Please help how i have to solve this?

Here is the 3rd picture

[image: layout with landscape screen]

Having problem on landscape orientation 
missing both button and textview and not getting any scroll.

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="20dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical|horizontal"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    />
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Full Name"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" >
        <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:background="@drawable/radius"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius"
        android:inputType="textPassword" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="Register" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom|center" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/signIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom|center"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:text="Sign In to addressbook"
    />

</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Please help I will be very thankful to you
Hello @Sam can you answer this question Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it scrollable, wrap your whole layout in a `ScrollView`. As @AbdulHannan mentions in his answer, you can define the preferred behavior (resize vs pan) in the AndroidManifest, or programmatically in onCreate() (but not in both -- it's redundant). If you just wrap it in a ScrollView, Android will automatically use `adjustResize` to resize your window, assuming that your ScrollView will handle the size change appropriately and be scrollable for the user.

Side design suggestion: That background is incredibly gaudy; try to make the pattern much more subtle if a pattern is necessary.

Comment: Scrollview didnt works i dont know why,
and i dont want keyboard on content of the layout i want layout like facebook application as in facebook aplication when keyboard appears whole layout content adjust automatically .
and still get problem on landscape screen :(
please help

Answer (score 0):

In your `Manifest.xml`, Under you're `<activity>` include this,
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan`
and in your `onCreate()` , add this:
`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` if you want the keyboard to be hidden whenever the `Activity` is created.

Comment: Scrollview didnt works i dont know why, and i dont want keyboard on content of the layout i want layout like facebook application as in facebook aplication when keyboard appears whole layout content adjust automatically . and still getting problem on landscape screen :( please help